# why use loTail.next = null and hiTail.next = null in java.util.HashMap#resize() in JDK1.8?

Tags: java, hashmap

**loTail.next = null** and **hiTail.next = null** in resize(), i think it is redundant? If anyone knows it, please tell me!

Comment: Please point to the specific line and the specific source.  We don't have the entire source code of an _old_ Java version handy.

Answer (score 0):

No, they are not redundant.

That section of code is taking a hash chain, iterating over the nodes, and reassigning them to either a "lo" or "hi" chain.  The statements you identified are executed when that process has finished.  They are making sure that the last nodes in the "lo" and "hi" chains both have `null` as their `next`.

If those statements weren't there, you could end up with some nodes appearing on *both* the "lo" and "hi" chains after the resize.  That would be *broken*.

This is the code section we are talking about from the Java 8 codebase

```
    else { // preserve order
        Node<K,V> loHead = null, loTail = null;
        Node<K,V> hiHead = null, hiTail = null;
        Node<K,V> next;
        do {
            next = e.next;
            if ((e.hash & oldCap) == 0) {
                if (loTail == null)
                    loHead = e;
                else
                    loTail.next = e;
                loTail = e;
            }
            else {
                if (hiTail == null)
                    hiHead = e;
                else
                    hiTail.next = e;
                hiTail = e;
            }
        } while ((e = next) != null);
        if (loTail != null) {
            loTail.next = null;            // <<< HERE
            newTab[j] = loHead;
        }
        if (hiTail != null) {
            hiTail.next = null;            // <<< HERE
            newTab[j + oldCap] = hiHead;
        }
    }
```